# Pass data from one component to another in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm new to angular i tried to send some formdata from one component to another by using service but it faces some issue ie , it shows error message as

> error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(data: any) => void'.

This is the component that i had my data

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JarwisService } from '../../Services/jarwis.service';
import { DataTransferService } from '../../dt-broker/dt-core/services/data-transfer.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-addlist',
  templateUrl: './addlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addlist.component.css']
})
export class AddlistComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private Jarwis:JarwisService,
               private dataTrans: DataTransferService,
               private router : Router,
               private http: HttpClient,
               private  _router : Router,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }


  preview(form: NgForm){
    this.Jarwis.getpreviewcontent(form.value).subscribe(
      viewdata => this.handlepreviewResponse(viewdata)
    );
  }
  handlepreviewResponse(data){
    this.dataTrans.setpreviewdata(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/previewad']);
  }

}
```

This is the component that i want to send the data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTransferService } from '../../../dt-broker/dt-core/services/data-transfer.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-previewad',
  templateUrl: './previewad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./previewad.component.scss']
})
export class PreviewadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataTrans: DataTransferService) { }

  public result=null;
  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.dataTrans.setpreviewdata);
    //alert(this.result);
   this.dataTrans.setpreviewdata.subscribe(message => this.result = message);
  }

}
```

This s the service that i wrote to transfer the data

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataTransferService {


  private previewdata = new BehaviorSubject('no data');
  datapreview = this.previewdata.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  setpreviewdata(data){
    return this.previewdata.next(data);
    //console.log(this.datapreview);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: you are getting a error on this line this.dataTrans.setpreviewdata.subscribe(message => this.result = message);?

Comment: yes in that line

Comment: and can you declare dataTrans public instead of private and try again ?

Comment: got yaa you declare private previewdata = new BehaviorSubject('no data'); as private change to the public

Comment: i tried this but same error exists

Comment: can you show us the full error

Comment: it still shows like this  " Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(data: any) => BehaviorSubject<any>'.
"

Comment: i just update my answer can you please check let me know if it is working or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - Pass an object from one component to another (no parent - child hierarchy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471726/angular-4-pass-an-object-from-one-component-to-another-no-parent-child-hier)

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring a BehaviorSubject private instead of public.

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class DataTransferService {


  public previewdata = new BehaviorSubject('no data');
  datapreview = this.previewdata.asObservable();

  constructor() { }


  setpreviewdata(data){
      this.previewdata.next(data);
      //console.log(this.datapreview);
    }

  getpreviewMessage(): Observable<any> {
      return this.previewdata.asObservable();
  }
 }
```

component you want to get the data

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { DataTransferService } from '../../../dt-broker/dt- 
     core/services/data-transfer.service';
   @Component({
      selector: 'ngx-previewad',
      templateUrl: './previewad.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./previewad.component.scss']
   })
   export class PreviewadComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private dataTrans: DataTransferService) { }

   public result=null;
   ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.dataTrans.setpreviewdata);
    //alert(this.result);
    this.dataTrans.getpreviewMessage.subscribe(message => this.result = 
    message);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can notice multiple mistakes here.

First thing to note is `BehaviorSubject.next` is void function. That's why you are getting this error and you are subscribing to value set not for the change.

So far as I understand you don't need `BehaviorSubject` here. Use `EventEmitter` instead.

Your service will be shape as follows.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataTransferService {
  public previewdata = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Send your data as follows

```js
----- bunch of code ----
export class AddlistComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private Jarwis:JarwisService,
               private dataTrans: DataTransferService,
               private router : Router,
               private http: HttpClient,
               private  _router : Router,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }


  preview(form: NgForm){
    this.Jarwis.getpreviewcontent(form.value).subscribe(
      viewdata => this.handlepreviewResponse(viewdata)
    );
  }
  handlepreviewResponse(data){
    this.dataTrans.previewdata.emit(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/previewad']);
  }

}
```

Receive data using subscription as below.

```js
--- bunch of code ---
export class PreviewadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataTrans: DataTransferService) { }

  public result=null;
  ngOnInit() {
   this.dataTrans.previewdata.subscribe(message => this.result = message);
  }

}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

finally i found my answer . It was my fault i called wrong function from service in the view component

```
export class PreviewadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dataTrans: DataTransferService) { }

  public result=null;
   ngOnInit() {
    this.dataTrans.datapreview.subscribe(message => this.result = message);
    // console.log(this.result);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a [small post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71098922/1042705) here to help get through services.. in these scenarios