# How can I get data from entryComponent to the component from where the entryComponent is called..?

Tags: angular, angular6

I created a Component 'Y' and called the entry component 'Z'.  this entry component 'Z' have a variable 'X'. I want the value of 'X' on my component'Y'. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Is 'Z' a child to the component to the 'Y'?

Comment: 'Z' is component, used in MatDialog and opened in a Pop up

Comment: I can help you if we have some code to work. For the instance I'll just say you can use `afterClosed` get the variable 'X', If you want to acquire it dynamically then I suggest use push and pull method using a serice since you can't bind the component as a `viewChild`. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428327/6434407). You don't need `BehaviorSubject` like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you injected it, that means you instantiated it yourself, then you can simply keep a reference on it and set the "entry component" property.

After creating your `ComponentPortal` you attached it to a `PortalOutlet` or an `OverlayRef`. The return value of `attach` contains the instance of the injected component.

For example, let's say your component is named `SomeComponent` and has a property named `someProperty`:

```
let portal = new ComponentPortal(componentFactory.componentType);

let component = overlayRef.attach<SomeComponent>(portal);

component.instance.someProperty = this.someOtherPropertyFromTheParentComponent
```